# Unable to get Sum of Column values(Checkbox checked) using jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Unable to get Sum of Column values(Checkbox checked) using jQuery Datatables. I'm trying to add sum of amount columns dynamically. If we uncheck amount will reduce automatically. I tried below code. Could you please suggest what could be the issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var creditAmount =0
    $('#firstTable').DataTable();
        
    $("#firstTable").on('change', function(){
    
    var checkedCount = $("#firstTable input:checked").length;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedCount; i++) {
    
       var amount =   $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text();   
         alert(amount);
       if (amount != "") {
        creditAmount += parseFloat(amount);
      } else {
        creditAmount = 0;
      }
     }
   $("#idSmofAmount").text(creditAmount);
    
    });

   
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <div>
        Count:: <span ="idSmofAmount"></span>
    </div>

<table id="firstTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox"/></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th><input type="checkbox"/></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found few issues in your code:

1. You refer to the first element of the table via `this` reference inside the `amount` variable
2. The `creditAmount` doesn't reset when the `change` event is triggered
3. The ID of the span element used to display the count wasn't properly defined

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var creditAmount = 0
  $('#firstTable').DataTable();

  $("#firstTable").on('change', function() {

    var checkedCount = $("#firstTable input:checked").length;
    var creditAmount = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < checkedCount; i++) {

      var amount = $("#firstTable input:checked")[i].parentNode.parentNode.children[4].innerHTML

      if (amount != "") {
        creditAmount += parseFloat(amount);
      } else {
        creditAmount = 0;
      }
    }

    $("#idSmofAmount").text(creditAmount);

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Count::
  <span id="idSmofAmount"></span>
</div>

<table id="firstTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```